# How to make multiple sounds play one after the other, when using a sequence array that gives back a number every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, audio, ibaction

Basically, I have an array set up so that when a button is pressed, it gives back values every second, which have been previously declared in the project.

I have four sounds in my project which I want to play instead of number values.

The code used is:

```
- (IBAction)playSeq:(UIButton *)sender
{
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (sender.tag == 1001)
    {
//        [app addNote:2];
//        [app addNote:3];
//        [app addNote:2];
//        [app addNote:0];
//        [app addNote:1];

        [app playSeq:@[@2, @3, @3, @0, @1]];
    }
}
```

Where the function `playSeq` is used, I want to be able to replace `[@2, @3, @3, @0, @1]` with the sounds equivalent to those numbers.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this please? Not as simple as merely replacing the numbers with the names of my audio files! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of the `playSeq` method could look something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
NSTimeInterval timeDelay = 0.0;
for (id sound in sounds) {
    dispatch_time_t dispatchDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(dispatchDelay, queue, ^{
        // Play the sound in whatever fashion you want
        [self play:sound];
    });
}
```

This doesn't give you a lot of control (like canceling etc.), but it may already be enough for your needs.

If not, consider using a custom `NSOperation` subclass for the sound playback task. Either give this class a `delay` property to delay the sound playback or create another `NSOperation` subclass whose only task is to wait for a specified delay. You could then add all those operations to an `NSOperationQueue` and create dependencies between the operations to execute them in order.

Comment: Is there no way to simply change the (`IBAction`)? For example if you did: `[app playSeq: playNote1, playNote2, playNote3, playNote4]];` ?

Comment: Not easily. If `playNote1`, `playNote2`, etc. were blocks you could certainly pass an array of blocks to a method, but then you would have to construct the blocks first and either the blocks or the `playSeq:` method would still have to handle the delay between the sounds. You would end up with something that resembles the code I showed above.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look into your example. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!